# Как подключать библиотеки? Как входить что писать в черные и синие экраны для установки библиотек?(на уровне системы)

Tags: c++, библиотеки

Если есть такие ссылки на гитхабе или стековерфлоу. От а до я. Где бы я мог полностью и из проверенных источников изучить подключение всех популярных opensourse библиотек.
Всех этих встраиваний в систему через черные и синие экраны, которые нужны(полезны) для установки самих библиотек(на уровне системы как я понимаю).

В основном, когда гуглю все это, там разобраны частные случаи, где пошагово разобрано что делать, чтобы получить ЛИШЬ ТО, что разбирается в данном уроке и НИЧЕГО БОЛЕЕ.

Может есть книги о том как это устроено, чтобы получить более широкий взгляд на вещи и понимать как можно "сходу" подключить любую библиотеку, и выставить нужные настройки\надстройки?

На гитхабе вся инфа оформлена в виде взаимосвязанных файлов - библиотек. А где прочитать о том, как мне это перенести в свою IDE? Чтобы работало, чтобы я мог сам модифицировать это, чтобы вообще разбираться в том, что там и для чего предназначено.

В первую очередь интересуют туториалы.

Comment: посоветую пару видео этого парня для начала https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=or1dAmUO8k0&list=PLlrATfBNZ98dudnM48yfGUldqGD0S4FFb&index=49 про статический и динамический линкинг

Comment: а что такое "черные и синие экраны"? (у меня есть пара идей, но я теряюсь)

Comment: @KoVadim поверщель и кмд

Comment: @KoVadim репозиторий и другие черные и синие экраны, в которые вписываются данные для установки библиотек(встраивания их в систему).

Comment: кмд - керамический магнитный диск? ах, это же консоль....

Comment: "другие черные и синие экраны" Какие еще экраны?.. Если не знаете, как это называется, то прикладывайте скрины, а то ничего не понятно. *"перенести в свою IDE"* Какая именно у вас IDE?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Там пояснено, когда эти "черные экраны" могут появляться - при подключении библиотек на системном уровне(на уровне кода) к IDE. Меня интересует сам туториал, в туториалах обычно разбираются разные варианты IDE. У меня VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле вы в кучу намешали все подряд.
Вам надо упорядочить информацию в своей голове для начала.

***Консоль***

Черный экран - это командная строка Windows (консоль), она же программа cmd.exe в системе. Можете найти её у себя на компьютере по пути `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`. Она служит для того, чтобы выполнять различные команды не из пользовательского интерфейса, а по старинке из консоли: создавать папки и файлы, удалять их, открывать и запускать другие программы в системе и многое другое. Служит для автоматизации рутинных действий.

Синий экран - это PowerShell `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\...`, более продвинутая оболочка, но работает по тому же принципу, что и cmd. Опять же, на ней удобно писать различные сценарии.

Можете изучить работу с командной строкой и с bat файлами, чтобы в вашей жизни магии было меньше.

***Библиотеки***

Библиотеками в windows являются обычно просто файлы DLL.

О том, как подключать к своей программе файлы DLL и сопутствующие им файлы .h с их описание, можно легко найти в интернете: "статическое и динамическое подключение DLL к проекту". Посмотреть видео, туториалы, почитать Рихтера. Написав пару своих собственных DLL файлов и подключив их к своему другому проекту, этот пункт вы тоже закроете.

***Сборка чужих библиотек***

А теперь о том, почему вы никогда не найдете подробного туториала под все случаи жизни.

По итогу библиотека DLL является особым образом скомпилированным кодом, который можно вызвать из сторонней программы и получить результат его выполнения. Представьте, как если бы один *.exe вызвал на выполнение другой *.exe и получил некоторый результат от него.

Не смотря на то, что вы можете вызвать чужой код из DLL, изначально он может быть написан на чем угодно и зависимости кода внутри DLL определяются исключительно разработчиком, который эту библиотеку в принципе сделал. При этом одна DLL спокойно может вызывать код из другой DLL. Или даже из сторонних DLL из других репозиториев и от других разработчиков, которые тоже надо перед использованием развернуть в системе.

Вспомните свои программы и попробуйте к ним написать общие инструкции по сборке. В лучшем случае будет готовый *.exe, в худшем описание как открыть Solution и прописать все возможные настройки и зависимости на целевом компьютере вашего друга (а еще сборка может пройти неуспешно по тем или иным причинам).

По факту инструкции на github, это инструкции к сборке, развертыванию и настройке отдельной программы, оформленный только в не привычный *.exe, а в эквивалетный DLL.

P.S>
В общем разберитесь с двумя первыми пунктами и остальное уже пойдет само собой.
Ну или придете и зададите вопрос уже с большим багажом знаний и терминов.